# USB OTG interface on Zedboard

Tags: usb

I am working on Zynq based zedboard designed by Avnet. I want to use USB functionality of Zedboard. I want to write C code on processor which access data from any attached device (E.g. Camera). Drivers are available given by Xilinx. Can anyone help me out in c code? How to use these functions.

```
int XUsbPs_EpBufferSend(XUsbPs InstancePtr, u8 EpNum, const u8 BufferPtr, u32 BufferLen);
int XUsbPs_EpBufferReceive(XUsbPs InstancePtr, u8 EpNum, u8 BufferPtr, u32 BufferLenPtr, u32 Handle);
```

I could not understand how to set value for EpNum & Handle.